# How to prevent inputs re-rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent React from re-rendering inputs when a user types into another input while using a single useState object to store the data. This wouldn't normally be an issue however the project is a dynamic form builder and contains 100s of inputs and other content and get quite laggy when typing.

Below is a very simple recreation of the issue, and when viewed with react dev tools I can see that all inputs are rerendered every time I type into one.

I've tried memoising the Input component as well us applying useCallback to the onChange handler, however neither seem to work.

```
const Container = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const onChange = useCallback((e) => {
        setData((data) => {
            const newData = { ...data };
            newData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
            return newData;
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Input
                type="text"
                name="field1"
                value={data?.field1 ?? ''}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Input
                type="text"
                name="field2"
                value={data?.field2 ?? ''}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Input
                type="text"
                name="field3"
                value={data?.field3 ?? ''}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const Input = memo(({ name, value, onChange }) => {
    return <input type="text" name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
});
```

I've spent the last few hours googling and trying suggestions but I can't seem to solve it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com) which perfectly handles extra re-renderings

Comment: Your code works as you see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hofstadter-rhq0mw?file=/src/App.js.